# Include proguard configuration file in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, proguard, pom.xml

I am trying to obfuscate java class files. I was using ant before, so i managed to obfuscate them during build process itself by including following code in 'build.xml'.

```
    <target name="-post-jfx-jar">
    <!-- obfuscate and optimize by ProGuard -->
    <taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties" classpath="lib/proguard.jar" />
    <proguard configuration="config.pro">
    </proguard>
    <move 
        file="${dist.jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" 
        tofile="${dist.jar}" verbose="true" overwrite="true" />
    </target>
```

'config.pro' is proguard configuration file.
Now i am trying to do same thing with maven. I am learning maven so i have no idea how to do same thing in 'pom.xml'. 
Thank you and sorry for bad English.

Comment: I've done this at work. If you can wait for Monday afternoon (CEST)... Or maybe someone else is quicker before. And, your English isn't bad at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <proguardVersion>5.0</proguardVersion>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <injar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</injar>
                <outjar>${project.build.finalName}-small.jar</outjar>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <proguardInclude>${basedir}/config.pro</proguardInclude>
                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: +1 IIRC this looks almost exactly like the POM I had used. With the only exception at `<phase>process-classes</phase>`: [_"post-process the generated files from compilation, for example to do bytecode enhancement on Java classes."_](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). This is exactly what ProGuard does and such your classes already obfuscated will be tested in the _test_ phase.

Answer (score 0):

The project I had used it in doesn't seem to exist any longer here. It was just a temporary test project. We decided not to use Proguard eventually.

However, I used the [proguard-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.github.wvengen%22) and created my POM according to its [Usage section](http://wvengen.github.io/proguard-maven-plugin/#Usage) in conjunction with the [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) manual.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I went through links you provided and finally came up with solution. I will answer this question with block of code i came up with.